# How to get event of clicking out of a QGraphicsItem, being notified of focusOut

Tags: qt, focus, qgraphicsitem

i have a class implemented from QGraphicsItem, called Node.

i have a rectangle shaped "Node" and i can do something when user clicked on it

i use mousePress and mouseRelease events.

but i want to be notified when user clicked "out of" the rectangle shape.

i tried to implement these functions:

Qt Code:

```
void Node::focusInEvent ( QFocusEvent * event){
cout<<"in"<<endl;
update();

QGraphicsItem::focusInEvent(event);
}
void Node::focusOutEvent ( QFocusEvent * event ){
cout<<"out"<<endl;
update();
QGraphicsItem::focusOutEvent(event);

}
void Node::hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event){
cout<<"out"<<endl;
}
```

these do not reacts if i click in or out of rectangle.
should i set a logic on my own for example getting the mouse position and control if it is out of rectangle?
or is there a built in method?

or how can a "Node" object know if other Node object is clicked?

also i wonder, googled but could not found that when does focusinevent and focusoutevent triggered? I guess focusOutEvent must work when i had clicked in the item, then out of the item, am i wrong?

thanks for idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you called [setFlags](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html#setFlags) method of your graphics item with **QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable** or **QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable** ?

According to QT doc.

> By default, no flags are enabled.

Comment: Thanks very much, i called setFlags(ItemIsSelectable|ItemIsMovable|ItemIsFocusable); and it is working perfectly. But when i am in another window , and then click to application window, the focusin and focusout works once, i am going to search for this. I had looked at the doc before ask but didnt see that i have to set flags. THanks again

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the following when you construct your nodes:

```
setFlag( QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable );
setAcceptHoverEvents( true );
```

The first line makes your item actually capable of receiving focus, and the latter makes it so your item is notified of mouse events.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and do you have an idea about when i am in another window , and then click to application window, the focusin and focusout works once, even if i did not click to my qgraphicsitem. The windows focusin event is triggered i think, how to avoid this?